# Laravel with Paypal Integration (Error code: UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ)

Tags: laravel, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I integrated Laravel with Paypal as a payment gateway. Everything works fine in the sandbox mode but I live mode I'm facing this issue in photo (https://i.ibb.co/x79hnnY/paypal-error.png) with the error code UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ in the URL. I really need your help guys. I searched a lot in the internet and I found several reasons such as currency and code errors but the most logic one is the country. Please note that I'm from a country that doesn't support Paypal but I really need your help if there is any solution guys.

I integrated Laravel with Paypal as a payment gateway. I'm expecting that live mode works like sandbox mode